# ¿Alguien sabe como instalar y usar ngx-particles.js para Angular 8?

Tags: angular, npm, particles

Quiero añadir particulas en un proyecto de Angular, sigo las instrucciones del sitio oficial:

1.- Install:  npm install ngx-particlesjs --save

2.- Usually:

```html
<ngx-particle [total]="total" [default_height]="300" [default_width]="300" [args]="args"></ngx-particle>
```

3.- Defining components:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  total = 150;
  args = {
    speed: 'fast',
    size: 1.2
  }
}
```

Bueno, lo que no entiendo es la parte 3 ¿Donde agrego ese código? Si alguien pudiera explicarme los pasos, y como configurarlo se lo agradeceria bastante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese código lo debes colocar en el componente donde vas a usar la directiva.

Por ejemplo si vas a usar la directiva en el AppComponent:

1. en el app.component.html agrega la directiva

`<ngx-particle [total]="total" [default_height]="300" [default_width]="300" [args]="args"></ngx-particle>`

2. En el app.component.ts agrega la configuración:

`total = 150;
  args = {
    speed: 'fast',
    size: 1.2
  }`

3. En el app.module.ts importa el módulo:

`import {NgxParticlesModule} from  'ngx-particlesjs';`

4. Agrega el módulo a los imports del AppModule

Te dejo ejemplo:

[Codigo ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2rzcnc)

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, acabo de añadir ese código en el componente donde lo usare pero no funciona, de hecho mi sitio web queda completamente en blanco y en consola me aparece el siguiente error: 

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'total' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-particle'.
1. If 'ngx-particle' is an Angular component and it has 'total' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-particle' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: De eso se trata el punto 3. Tienes que importar el NgxParticlesModule dentro del módulo donde se encuentra declarado tu componente. Y luego el punto 4 agregar el NgxParticlesModule al imports:[] de ese mismo módulo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu paciencia, a funcionado perfectamente. Te lo agradezco bastante :D.